# How to use data given in html href in android

Tags: android, html

I am new to android. I loaded a `html` page in android `webview`, in that `html` file I have given `"href"` in which instead of giving link to any `html` file or any site I have given some values like `"callme?number=0456234543"`. while clicking the link it has to display a popup with the given number.

But I do not know how to trigger this in android. I thought that `WebViewClient` will be used for this even though i don know how to code this.

Can anyone help me with source code for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to [hyperlink your phone number](http://www.marketingtechblog.com/hyperlink-phone-number/)?

Something like below

```
<a href="tel:0094775373891">94-77-5373891</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use tel keyword in your link instead of callme

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                    Uri.parse(url)); 
            startActivity(intent); 
    }else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
}
```

and your link look like this `<a href="your_number">your_number</a>`

**Edit**

you can inject the code into the loading page at on page start/finish time using this way

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { ... })()");
```

Here in the function you can write replace code for your element using `DOM`
and impelement in both `onPageStarted()` and `onPageFinished()`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Sorry Forgot to mention onething. this data should be controlled by server

Comment: can you more elaborate about this